# Redirect from Jquery to an action in controller asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to redirect to a different url when i click the submit button, this is the jquery code on the first view

```
    $('#Submit-ids').click(function () {
    var ids = [1, 2, 3, 4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("Payment", "Screenings")",
        data: JSON.stringify(ids),
    success: function () {
        alert("Succesfully made your payment");
    },
    contentType: 'application/json'
});
})
```

now, my controller who handles the database is this:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Payment(IEnumerable<int> ids)
    {

        foreach (int element in ids)
        {
            var screening = new Screening {
                Seat = element.ToString()
            };
            _context.Screenings.Add(screening);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
    }
```

but when i click the button (the one with the id = 'Submit-ids') the page doesn't redirect and my url on the address bar gets a '?' character at the end.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using ajax then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not make sense to return a Redirect response for an ajax call. If you are making an ajax call and want to do the redirect when it is finished, you should do the redirect on your `done` event of the ajax call.  You can probably return the url you want to redirect to , from the server action method.

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
    return Json(new { status = "success", url = Url.Action("Index", "Home") });
}
return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
```

And in your ajax call's success/`done` event, inspect the response json and redirect as needed

```
$.ajax({

}).done(function(res){
   if(res.status==='success')
   {
      window.location.href=res.url;  // This will issue a new GET request to Index action
   }
   else
   {
     alert("Some thing unexpected happened. show a proper error message to user");
   }
});
```

**But** again, doing a redirect in an ajax call does not makes much sense as the whole idea behind using ajax is to give the user a partial page update experience (no full page reload/navigation).  You may simply not use ajax and do a normal form submission, where you can use the `return RedirectToAction`

Comment: Sorry i'm kind of new in javascript, jquery and ajax, i'm using ajax because that's the way i found to send an array (the array in my question is an example), and when the button #submit-ids is pressed i wanted the transaction to end a redirect to the index, thanks this was very helpful :D